# how to automate siebel tools through scripts like importing objects and compiling them?

Tags: automation, siebel

Could anyone help in automating the job by running the script.how to automate siebel tools through scripts like importing objects and compiling them ?

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far?

Comment: siebdev.exe /c tools.cfg /d  BTQA /u SADMIN /p hdqs!ebpfix /t choice_benefit /batchimport "Siebel Repository" overwrite "D:\SlikSvn\9thaugbtqa" import.log

Comment: @srikantht You might want to edit/delete that comment if it has your SADMIN password  in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two steps:

- import files
- full compile

Import sif files:

```
siebdev.exe /c "tools_DEV1.cfg" /d ServerDataSrc /u SADMIN /p SADMIN /batchimport "Siebel Repository" overwrite c:\import import_DEV1.log
```

Full compile:

```
siebdev.exe /c "tools_DEV1.cfg" /u SADMIN /p SADMIN /d ServerDataSrc /tl ENU /bc "Siebel Repository"  c:\srf\siebel_sia_AUTO_ENU.srf
```

references: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/UsingTools/compile_test_trouble7.html